# grep matched lines to one file and matched strings to another file

Tags: bash, grep

I want to search lines with timestamps in a log file (not all lines have timestamps) and I also would like to keep those timestamps so I can see the timespan, the active day number, etc.

```
201 3083560 2013-10-21T13:57:55.334+0200    time|bootup
202 3083560 2013-10-21T13:57:55.334+0200    startup
204 3083579 2013-10-21T13:57:55.353+0200    system|device
205 3083579 2013-10-21T13:57:55.353+0200    system|manufacturer
206 3083579 2013-10-21T13:57:55.353+0200    system|model
```

I can run the commands:

```
grep -P  '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}[+-]\d{4}\t' usr.log > file1.txt
grep -Po '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}[+-]\d{4}\t' usr.log > file2.txt
```

And my question is, can I run grep only once to get what I need with some pipes? The pattern stays the same so I guess grep once could save me some time, as I have 30k individual user log files.

*It's useful to keep the tab at the end of the pattern, because in some lines there are time values in the last column so I need to exclude `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}[+-]\d{4}\n`.

*My environment is CentOS 7, grep (GNU) 2.20.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't have to run it twice, you can use `grep -oP` in the `usr.log` directly.

Comment: Also your regex `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}\d{2}\.\d{3}[+-]\d{4}\t` or `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}\d{2}.\d{3}[+-]\d{4}\n` is not matching the lines in your sample input file

Comment: Thanks! I've forgot to put an extra : in the pattern. Now I've fixed it. But how can it be done in one run? I want to keep file1.txt too.

Comment: You have not fixed it actually, the output is still empty running on your input file. Also can you state your requirement clearly once again with a proper example and an exact expected output.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, although it runs fine on my side. I'm not quite sure what problem you are facing... Is it because the five lines I listed above don't actually contain tabs?

Comment: Can you output your `grep` version as `grep --version` and paste it here, mine is `grep (GNU grep) 2.26` and update the input file exactly as you are running

Comment: Certainly, mine is 2.20. But I don't know how to put tabs here. I copied from SublimeText with tabs and paste in the SO input box. I don't think you can copy tabs out of the webpage.

Comment: Does lines without a time stamp has a first character that is not a number? If so perhaps `grep  '\d` will do

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done by one `grep`, but you can get away with reading the file once and reusing `grep`'s output, if you send the output of one grep to the other:

```
regex='\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}[+-]\d{4}\t' 
grep -P "$regex" usr.log | tee file1.txt | grep -Po "$regex" > file2.txt
```

`tee file` saves the input to the file, and prints to stdout as well, making it useful to save output in the middle of a pipe.

If you can use `awk`, then you can take advantage of it being the third field, and do it in one run:

```
awk '/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}.[0-9]{4}\t/ \
  {print $3 > "file2.txt"; print}' usr.log > file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run your regex in perl you can split your output between stdout and stderr using the `$&` variable to print only the matched string:

```
perl -ne 'if(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}[+-]\d{4}/){print; print STDERR "$&\n"}' usr.log > file1.txt 2> file2.txt
```